# How print wchar_t using function write

Tags: c

How print to stdout `wchar_t` in C using function write form `<unistd.h>`

I found this code but without explanation. I want to understand how it works and how to print `wchar_t` using `write()`

```
void print_unicode(wchar_t c)
{
    char str[5];

    if (c < 0x80) {
        str[0] = ((c >> 0) & 0x7F) | 0x00;
        str[1] = '\0';
        str[2] = '\0';
        str[3] = '\0';
        str[4] = '\0';
    }
    else if (c < 0x0800) {
        str[0] = ((c >> 6) & 0x1F) | 0xC0;
        str[1] = ((c >> 0) & 0x3F) | 0x80;
        str[2] = '\0';
        str[3] = '\0';
        str[4] = '\0';
    }
    else if (c < 0x010000) {
        str[0] = ((c >> 12) & 0x0F) | 0xE0;
        str[1] = ((c >> 6 ) & 0x3F) | 0x80;
        str[2] = ((c >> 0 ) & 0x3F) | 0x80;
        str[3] = '\0';
        str[4] = '\0';
    }
    else if (c < 0x110000) {
        str[0] = ((c >> 18) & 0x07) | 0xF0;
        str[1] = ((c >> 12) & 0x3F) | 0x80;
        str[2] = ((c >> 6 ) & 0x3F) | 0x80;
        str[3] = ((c >> 0 ) & 0x3F) | 0x80;
        str[4] = '\0';
    }
    write(1, str, strlen(str));
}
```

Comment: UTF-32 -> UTF-8. What more explanation could you *possibly* need?

Comment: There's no right answer to the question "how do I print a `wchar_t` value using [a function that doesn't take a `wchar_t` argument]" unless you also know, and tell us, the actual encoding used by your C library's `wchar_t` *and* the actual encoding that should be used in the file, tty, or other data sink that you are writing to. (They are almost never the same.)

Comment: The function shown does the job if and only if `wchar_t` is encoded in UTF-32, the data sink expects UTF-8, *and* higher level code enforces that no codepoint from plane 18 or higher will ever be used. Otherwise it will not do the job.

Comment: @zwol and UTF-32 is defined as not having plane 18 or higher, so.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala At the present rate of allocation, that's going to have to change no later than 580 years from now. Also, even if that doesn't concern you, there's no good reason for this function to have undefined behavior on out-of-range values. I would have written it to emit five- and six-byte sequences per the original definition of UTF-8, but it would also be acceptable to drop higher codepoints or map them to U+FFFD.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`wctomb()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/wctomb) to convert the wide character to a locale-dependent multibyte format, and then write those bytes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void print_wchar(wchar_t w) {
  char buf[MB_CUR_MAX];
  int len = wctomb(buf, w);
  if (len > 0) {
    if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, len) != len) {
      perror("write");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  } else {
    fputs("Cannot convert wide character to multibyte!\n", stderr);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
}

int main(void) {
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
  wchar_t w = L'\u00C2'; // LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX
  print_wchar(w);
  return 0;
}
```

In a UTF-8 locale, this will write the two bytes `0xC3 0x82` (The UTF-8 representation of U+00C2).

Answer (score 0):

Code only make sense if `wchar_t` is encoded as UTF32 and `stdout` expects `UTF8`.

> **STDC_ISO_10646** An integer constant of the form yyyymmL (for example, 199712L). If this symbol is defined, then every character in the Unicode required set, when stored in an object of type `wchar_t`, has the same value as the short identifier of that character. The Unicode required set consists of all the characters that are defined by ISO/IEC 10646, along with all amendments and technical corrigenda, as of the specified year and month. If some other encoding is used, the macro shall not be defined and the actual encoding used is implementation-defined.

---

Do not use `strlen()` to find the count to write as `char str[5];` is not used as a *string*, but a character array.

Code such as `str[0] = ((c >> 0) & 0x7F) | 0x00;` can generate a *null character* when `c == 0` then `write(1, str, strlen(str));` will write nothing.

---

```
#ifndef __STDC_ISO_10646__
#error TBD code 
#endif

//void print_unicode(wchar_t c)
void print_unicode(wchar_t c)
{
    unsigned char str[4];
    size_t sz = 0; 

    if (c < 0x80) {
        str[0] = ((c >> 0) & 0x7F) | 0x00;
        sz = 1;
    }
    else if (c < 0x0800) {
        str[0] = ((c >> 6) & 0x1F) | 0xC0;
        str[1] = ((c >> 0) & 0x3F) | 0x80;
        sz = 2;
    }
    else if (c < 0x010000) {
        // ToDo: look for surrogates and error out on them
        str[0] = ((c >> 12) & 0x0F) | 0xE0;
        str[1] = ((c >> 6 ) & 0x3F) | 0x80;
        str[2] = ((c >> 0 ) & 0x3F) | 0x80;
        sz = 3;
    }
    else if (c < 0x110000) {
        str[0] = ((c >> 18) & 0x07) | 0xF0;
        str[1] = ((c >> 12) & 0x3F) | 0x80;
        str[2] = ((c >> 6 ) & 0x3F) | 0x80;
        str[3] = ((c >> 0 ) & 0x3F) | 0x80;
        sz = 4;
    }
    else {
      Handle_Error();
      return;
    }
    write(1, str, sz);
}
```